# Java Error: Using custom class outside of file returns cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I am used to writing in Python and I find that Java's strict object oriented style is difficult to work with.

I have a simple file setup as follows:

```
./filetest
└── main.java
└── ReadSelectWord.java
```

I am trying to use the public `ReadSelectWord` class (defined inside `ReadSelectWord.java`) in my `main.java` file.

Here's what I have:

---

### ReadSelectWord.java

```java
package filetest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class ReadSelectWord {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String selectedWord = ReadFile();
        System.out.println(selectedWord); // Prints the selected word to the console for testing purposes.
        
    }
    
    // The following code reads the word list file and selects a random word from the list of words.
    public static String ReadFile() throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

### main.java

```java
package filetest;

public class main {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            ReadSelectWord obj = new ReadSelectWord();
        }
}
```

---

I try executing it with my terminal using `javac ReadSelectWord.java` and then `javac main.java` however, compiling `main.java` returns two `cannot find symbol` errors:

```
main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                        ReadSelectWord x = new ReadSelectWord();
                        ^
  symbol:   class ReadSelectWord
  location: class main
main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                        ReadSelectWord x = new ReadSelectWord();
                                               ^
  symbol:   class ReadSelectWord
  location: class main
2 errors
```

Comment: Did you mean `javac main.java`?

Comment: @MCEmperor yes, just edited now

Comment: Also, make sure to place your files in the correct directory (`./filetest`).

Comment: @MCEmperor Just moved the files, the error still pops up

Comment: Since you're using packages, you'll need an actual directory structure that is associated with them (i.e. a `filetest` folder). The command will need to be run in the correct directory context as well. I would strongly recommend an IDE for getting started with development, and there are quite a few ways of doing things in Java that are different from a Python project's workflow.

Comment: You should be in the parent folder of filetest.  Then javac filetest/*.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you add *main* method to ReadSelectWord class?
Also your ReadSelectWord class has only static methods so you don't have to create an instance of it:)

You can try to rewrite your code in that way:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadSelectWord
  {
    final private String filename;
    
    public ReadSelectWord(String filename)
    {
      this.filename=filename;
    }
    public void ReadWord() 
    {
      String selectedWord;
      try 
        {
          selectedWord = ReadFile();
        }
      catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
          selectedWord = "File not found!";
        } 
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
          selectedWord = "Unknown Error!";
        }
      System.out.println(selectedWord);
    }
    private String ReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
      ...   
     
      return ...;
    }
    
  }
```

The main class:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ReadSelectWord obj = new ReadSelectWord("text.txt"); 
    obj.ReadWord();
  }
}
```

You can play with my simple working live example on [ReplIt](https://replit.com/@Babich/StackOverflowQuestion#Main.java)

Comment: What is the point of the fileName attribute? It looks like its just stored and nothing is done with it

Comment: filename attribute is using inside ReadFile method (this logic showed as ...) to read from the file (check out my live demo on ReplIt).
But this is just a sample....